# How do I find my user name in recovery mode?

Tags: themes, recovery-mode, username

I installed a lock screen theme and it gives a blank screen when it loads. So I figured out how to delete it but I need my username. Can any one help?

Answer (score 3):

A user's *home directory name* will usually be the same as the username, so one way would be

```
ls /home
```

A more formal way would be to look at the password entries for non-system users e.g.

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 999 {print $1}'
```